# How to download a Byte Array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, download

So, using vb.net, I retrieve from my server the byte data for a file that the user wishes to download. I always know what the filename and extension is, but what I don't know is how to start downloading the byte data and in the proper file format. How do I got about doing this?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I already retrieve the data in byte format in code, I just need to download it as the proper file type which is also known. I'm keeping the URL to the file hidden at all times so it's never exposed.

Comment: Try this (C#, easy to translate): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711.aspx

Comment: That seems to need a url. I never wish to expose file location, especially since I already retrieve the data in byte format.

Comment: It's not clear...if you have the bytes then what do you have to download more? Can't you just save it?

Comment: The user is the one downloading. I'm retrieving the data and now I need the user to start downloading it, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are still unclear. "Downloading" means "transfering a file from a (web) server to a client (PC)". So, if the you have already retrieved the data, what is there left to "download"?

Comment: The data itself. I got the data stored in a bytearray variable that then needs to be downloaded.

Anyway, I was able to figure it out finally. I don't have enough reputation to post the code at the moment, so I'll answer it later.

Comment: You CANNOT download something or access a resource without URL ! You have to understand that !
It depends on what you want but there may be other things you could do like encrypting the byte()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Using BinaryWrite with the other Response functions like AddHeader and ContentType I got it to work. GetMimeType is a function I made. Code below:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName)
Response.ContentType = GetMimeType(FileName)
Response.BinaryWrite(data)
Response.End()
Response.Flush()
```

Thanks to those who tried to help!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Could you please share your function GetMimeType?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download the file directly to the hard drive, the easiest solution is to use [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx). The MSDN page contains a nice example.

If you want to put the file into a byte array instead of a file on disk, use [WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) instead:

```
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
Dim myByteArray = myWebClient.DownloadData("http://...")
```

Again, a larger example can be found on the MSDN page.

If you want your program to stay responsive while downloading, check out [the asynchronous versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190.aspx) of those methods.

---

EDIT: I'm still having a hard time understanding your situation, but it you *already have a byte array* and just want to *write it to the disk*, you can use [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\my\path\myfile.bin", myByteArray)
```

Comment: Wanting to download the byte data to the users hard drive. The file is stored in byte format on the server. I'll check out that first link, second doesn't sound like what I want.

Comment: Nevermind! Both are requiring a url. The data is hidden so there isn't supposed to be a visible URL to the user.

Comment: If I wasn't hiding the file locations then those would be good.

Comment: @Mitchell: I still don't fully understand your requirements, but I've modified my answer. Maybe this helps you?

Comment: I already figured out, but I'll see if I can at least try and explain it.
I send a query to the database requesting the file's byte data.
The database returns the byte data and I store it in the byte array.
I then needed to start downloading that data.

That's where I got stuck, I didn't know how to download data without a url.